# unity webgl facebook login error

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, unity-webgl

So I have a problem when I try login in to facebook with FB.login in javascript. I get a popup saying
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Ive seen a lot of people having this issue, and answer about it,
so Ive tried to changes the setting of my facebook app.
1) put localhost in app domains
2) add a website platform and localhost in url
3) enable embedded browser oauth login
4) add localhost in valid oauth redirect urls

and nothing worked. i tried also with http:// localhost instead of just local host.

Im using apache server to test my app,

you guys have any idea how to do it properly?

Comment: Have you tried setting site url to `http://localhost/`? Without spaces at all (that's what I see in `http:// localhost`) and with trailing '/'.